# Order of the zero of an analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to show that the order of the zero of an analytic function $f(z)$ at $z_0$ is the smallest $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f^{(k)}(z_0) \neq 0$.

I set $f(z) =  (z-z_0)^kg(z)$ for an analytic function $g(z)$ with $g(z_0)\neq 0$.  I'm unsure how to prove the assertion.

Comment: Since what you need to show is often the definition of the order of a zero: Which definition are you using?

Comment: Expand $g$ in a power series around $z_0$. This will give the power series for $f$ from which you can read off the values of $f^{(k)}(z_0)$.

Comment: what is your definition of  oder of zero?